# JniHandleOwnership in Mono for Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Can someone explain to me what the exact meanings of the three [JniHandleOwnership](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) enum values in Mono for Android are? What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies for not updating the class library documentation yet.

The [Binding Android Types](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Binding_Android_Types) documentation states what the various `JniHandleOwnership` values mean in the  [Wrapping with Java.Lang.Object](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Binding_Android_Types#Wrapping_with_Java.Lang.Object) section.

*Update* based on comments:

- `JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer` should be used if *nothing* should be done with the `handle` parameter. This should always be used within [*connector methods*](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Binding_Android_Types#Complete_Adder_Binding).
- `JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef` should be used when you have a local reference (e.g. you called `JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod()`, which returns a local reference) and you want to pass ownership of the local reference to a wrapper.
- `JniHandleOwnership.TransferGlobalRef` should be used when you have a global reference and you want to pass ownership of the global reference to a wrapper:

  ```
  IntPtr grefFoo = JNIEnv.FindClass("Foo"); // FindClass() returns a gref
  var Foo = Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<Java.Lang.Class>(grefFoo, JniHandleOwnership.TransferGlobalRef);
  ```

Comment: I still don't completely understand this. Is this definition correct? DoNotTransfer: Delete ref manually | TransferLocalRef: Ref deleted in constructor | TransferGlobalRef: Ref deleted in destructor/finalizer | Why would I want to keep the reference (i.e. why would I want to user TransferGlobalRef)?

Comment: Why would you want to use `TransferGlobalRef`? Because you have a global ref and you want to "pass ownership" of it so that you don't need to worry about it: IntPtr grefFoo = JNIEnv.FindClass("Foo"); /* JNIEnv.FindClass() returns a gref */ var Foo = Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<Java.Lang.Class>(grefFoo, JniHandleOwnership.TransferGlobalRef);

Comment: Found this link that may clarify the whole thing a little bit more: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/jni-tips.html#local_vs_global_references